# RegEx for replacing nth specific character

Tags: regex, string, replace

I have a string that is `cmpm04` what is the regex to remove the 2nd `m` in this value?  I would like for the output to be `cmp04`.

I have tried something like this, `\m(?=\cmp04)` but cannot figure out how to access the index.  This is for a larger data set where the 2nd `m` will need to be removed.

Comment: Use `^([^m]*m[^m]*)m`, replace with `$1` (or `\1`)

Comment: What do you mean replace with `$1 or \1`. I am novice in regex.  I will be entering this expression into an interface which calculates my value based on my expression

Comment: If you want to *remove* a match using a regex, there must be some way to enter the replacement pattern, right? Well, if the engine is PCRE, you may use `^[^m]*m[^m]*\Km`.

Comment: Perhaps state what library/language you are using to do matching and replacing, and the answer can be framed for that.
For example, in perl it would be:

`my $s = 'cmpm04';   $s =~ s/^([^m]*m[^m]*)m/$1/;`

Comment: Use `(?<=cmp)m(?=\d+)` replace with nothing. To do this inverse,  concaetenate `$1$2` after using `(cmp)m(\d+)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Wiktor Stribiżew suggests excellent expression. It is just alternative:

```regex
^.*?(m).*?(\g1)
```